# Nested Loops on verilog not behaving as expected

Tags: verilog

I have a problem with verilog.
So the structure for my code is I have top module,
then have another 2 sub-module that I called on the top module

Here's some of my code

```
genvar i;
genvar j;
wire[2:0] encoder[7:0]; //4bit reg array of 8 element
wire[8:0] save_tmp[7:0];
wire [8:0] tmp; //1bit

generate
    for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin: gen_loop
        module1 mod1(.prev(0), .cur(1), .next(1), .out(encoder[i]));               
        
        for(j=0;j<N;j=j+1) begin: gen_ppg
            module2 mod2(.encoded(encoder[i]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[j]));
        end
        assign save_tmp[i] = tmp;
    end
endgenerate
```

I can get the output from the first module (through encoder) and also no problem when I sent it into the second module (module2). Here's my second module:

```
module module2(encoded, in1, in2, out);
    input [2:0] encoded; 
    input in1, in2; 
    output out;
    
    wire nand1, nand2;
    
    assign nand1 = ~(in1 & encoded[2]);
    assign nand2 = ~(in2 & encoded[1]);
    
    assign out =  ~(nand1 & nand2) ^ encoded[0];
endmodule
```

I'm trying to make a testbench just for calling module2 and it's working.
But when I put it on the top function, I can get the value from nand1 and nand2 but not the output.

[image]
Can anyone knows the problem ?

Comment: + you should add full codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each index of `tmp` as more than one driver. If any of the drivers values conflict, the result is an X. Each index of `tmp` needs to have only one driver. There are two ways to do this.

One is to add more bits to `tmp` and assign explicitly:

```
genvar i;
genvar j;
wire[2:0] encoder[7:0]; //4bit reg array of 8 element
wire[8:0] save_tmp[7:0];
wire [8:0] tmp [7:0]; //1bit <-- Add range [7:0]

generate
    for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin: gen_loop
        module1 mod1(.prev(0), .cur(1), .next(1), .out(encoder[i]));               
        
        for(j=0;j<N;j=j+1) begin: gen_ppg
            module2 mod2(.encoded(encoder[i]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[i][j])); // <-- Add [i]
        end
        assign save_tmp[i] = tmp[i]; // <-- Add [i]
    end
endgenerate
```

The other approach is the declare `tmp` inside the generate loop. Then each index of the loop will have its own scope limited instance.

```
genvar i;
genvar j;
wire[2:0] encoder[7:0]; //4bit reg array of 8 element
wire[8:0] save_tmp[7:0];

generate
    for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin: gen_loop
        wire [8:0] tmp; //1bit <-- tmp is now local to the gen_loop index
        module1 mod1(.prev(0), .cur(1), .next(1), .out(encoder[i]));               
        
        for(j=0;j<N;j=j+1) begin: gen_ppg
            module2 mod2(.encoded(encoder[i]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[j]));
        end
        assign save_tmp[i] = tmp;
    end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

If `N` is greater than 1, then you will have contention on the `tmp` signals, resulting in unknowns (`x`).

For example, assume N=2. If you were to unroll the nested `for` loops, you would have 4 instances of the `module2` module like this:

```
module2 mod2_00 (.encoded(encoder[0]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[0]));
module2 mod2_01 (.encoded(encoder[0]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[1]));
module2 mod2_10 (.encoded(encoder[1]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[0]));
module2 mod2_11 (.encoded(encoder[1]), .in1(1'b0), .in2(1'b0), .out(tmp[1]));
```

The 1st and the 3rd lines both drive the `tmp[0]` net, which is contention, resulting in `x`.

Similarly, the 2nd and the 4th lines both drive the `tmp[1]` net.

You need to rework your design to avoid multiple drivers of the same net.